# Hyundai Tucson died while driving; will not start

Tags: hyundai, diesel, fuel-injection, tucson

I have a Hyundai Tucson 2011 directed injected diesel which has just broken down. What happened is that while driving the engine suddenly stopped and won't start.  There is no check engine light on.

The engine just cranks but won't start at all. one mechanic told me its the diesel high pressure pump and another said its the capacitor for the pump but I can't find the capacitor I don't even know what it looks like ?? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The right direction is heading towards a garage with a diagnostic computer. Just about anything that would cause an engine to stop should leave some type of error message - unless, of course, the culprit is the ECU itself. But it would be quite amazing for one of those to just quit with no messages, either. Unfortunately, modern mechanics does have to deal with the electronic issues as well.